# spring application in kotlin behaving wierdly

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, retrofit2

I am completely new on Spring + Kotlin, and am trying to write a simple server. I am trying to write an executable example code of one app server receiving request from the client, and sending the request to another server, which will return result, and the app server will return that result to the client.

I bounded the server on localhost:9000, and when I send the request to `localhost:9000/music?user=whatever`, I first got a result I expected as below.

```
[
    "Music(Genre=Rock, Mood=[Joyful, Depressed])"
]
```

However, sending the same request again(Using postman), I got `[]` as a return. I can't understand this behavior as I expect the same result to be returned every time I send a request. The sample inputs are hard coded in controller code, as a variable named sampleList. I aim to change this part, by receiving this variable as a request body from the client after I resolve this problem.

Can anyone explain why this unexpected behavior is shown?
Thanks much in advance. The codes are shown below.

```
package org.whatever

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*
import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Callback
import retrofit2.Response

@RestController
class MusicController {

    @GetMapping("/music")
    fun retrieveMusicInfo(@RequestParam(value = "user") user: String): MutableList<String> {
        val valList = mutableListOf<String>()

        val sampleList: List<Int> = listOf(1, 2, 3, 4)
        val sampleAmplitudes = Amplitudes(sampleList)
        MusicService.create()?.genreMoodRequest(sampleAmplitudes).enqueue(object : Callback<Music> {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Music>, t: Throwable) { // Whatever }
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Music>, response: Response<Music>?) {
                val data = response?.body()?.toString()
                data?.let { valList.add(it) }
            }
        })
        return valList
    }
}
```

The service logic is as below.

```
package org.whatever

import retrofit2.Call
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.Body
import retrofit2.http.Headers
import retrofit2.http.POST

interface MusicService {
    @Headers("accept: application/json",
            "content-type: application/json")
    @POST("/")
    fun genreMoodRequest(@Body params: Amplitudes)
        : Call<Music>

    companion object {
        fun create(): MusicService {
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://localhost:5000")
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build()

            return retrofit.create(MusicService::class.java)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: its probably something like the accept header isn't being sent via postman. Is the first request (the one that works) from a browser?

Comment: @stringy05 No it wasn't. The working request was from postman, and the following (not working and returning empty string) request was also from postman.

Comment: well thats strange. Not sure it will help, but if you add the request and response headers from the working and then failing request there might be some detail there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Problem

Retrofit `enqueue()` is working asynchronously. so it doesn't block the current thread that handles a request.

As a result, The thread can be done before it receives a response from the Retrofit client.

### solutions

1. use spring `RestTemplate` instead of Retrofit
2. use retrofit with blocking API (not `enqueue()`)